# Python regular expression again - match URL

Tags: python, regex

I have such a regular expression:

```
 re.compile(r"((https?):((//)|(\\\\))+[\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+-=\\\.&]*)", re.MULTILINE|re.UNICODE)
```

But that doesn't include [hashbangs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) `(#!)`. What do I need to change to get it working? I know I can add `!` to a group with `#@%`, etc., but that will select something like

```
Check this out: http://example.com/something/!!!
```

And I want to avoid that.

Comment: How about checking out the RFC for URI syntax (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)?  It will show you that the bang can only be used in certain ways otherwise it has to be escaped.  Good question.

Comment: I hope you're not trying to use this regex to match URLs requested by a browser: if so, you should realise that the part after the hash is *not* sent in a normal client request.

Comment: No. I'm parsing user input and make links shorter and safer for users (we have full control, we can block link, domain etc.). And with original regex there was http://ourshortdomain.foo/urlhash/#!/twitter/something ;)

Comment: The canonical question is *[How can I split a URL string up into separate parts in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449775/)* (2009).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't try to make your own regular expression for matching URLs. Use someone else's who has already solved such problems, like [this one](https://gist.github.com/gruber/8891611).

Comment: While there's nothing wrong in using somebody's else code, there's nothing wrong in writing your own either! :) I think if everybody would follow the recommendation _"Don't try to make your own <put_whatever_here>, use someone else's"_ we would still all be living in caves! ;)

Comment: @mac - If everyone had to reinvent everything, we'd make progress much more slowly.  Far better to use someone else's completed idea and then make it better by improving it or adding something new to it.  Even Newton acknowledged that he was building on the foundation of others' work.

Comment: @Mark - I surely don't argue with that and I never said that _everybody_ should reinvent the wheel! :) I just hold that there is not an hard rule to follow: sometimes it make sense to use other's work, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: @mac - You're absolutely right.  However, we should gently nudge those who write horrific regular expressions into copying others' work until they gain enough knowledge so as to not leave a nightmare of others to maintain. :) :)

Comment: The method in this link doesn't match some valid urls, specifically url shorteners. I'd put an example, but SO doesn't let me put shortened urls.  But specifically, it doesn't work with Twitter's shortener, `'https:// +  't.co' + '/blah'`.

Comment: The updated one in Gruber's gist works with the t.co URLs. I'll update the link.

Comment: @kindall It turns out I made a goof.  PyCharm for whatever reason, when you let it fix lines that are too long, and your line is a triple-quoted string, it inserts a space at the end of your string...

Comment: The regex in the link is terrible: it attempts to list year 2011 known Top Level Domains and becomes VERY quickly OBSOLETE.

Answer (score 10):

It could be very long but in practice mine works pretty good. Please try this one
`((http|https)\:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\?\:@\-_=#]+\.([a-zA-Z]){2,6}([a-zA-Z0-9\.\&\/\?\:@\-_=#])*`

It matches all of the example below

```
http://wwww.stackoverflow.com
abc.com
http://test.test-75.1474.stackoverflow.com/
stackoverflow.com/
stackoverflow.com
rfordyce@broadviewnet.com
http://www.example.com/etcetc
www.example.com/etcetc
example.com/etcetc
user:pass@example.com/etcetc
(www.itmag.com)
example.com/etcetc?query=aasd
example.com/etcetc?query=aasd&dest=asds
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427530/regular-expression-pattern-to-
match-url-with
www/Christina.V.Scott@gmail.com
line.lundvoll.nilsen@telemed.no.
s.hossain@unsw.edu.au
s.hossain@unsw.edu.au
```

Comment: I tried your regex with my sample text `i opened https://google.com and http://speedtest.net and www.standford.edu` but I don't get proper result. This is how I get `[('https://', 'https', 'm', ''),
 ('http://', 'http', 't', ''),
 ('', '', 'u', '')]`

Comment: It depends on were you are trying. If you are using python(don't need back slash \ chars) or jave or something else. Please try out his one here https://regexr.com/

Comment: Unfortunately this approach matches with some unexpected strings like ```matches if you have.any.point that not necessarily is.a.site```, you can paste on pythex.org to see

Comment: This doesn't recognize strings like `https://google/` which might be used as valid URLs. Your regex requires a `.com` or `.net` at the end.

Answer (score 6):

This is a common problem. Use default libraries.

For Python, use [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html).

Comment: urlparse would still parse OP's problem URL: urlparse.urlparse('http://example.com/something/!!!')

Comment: Well that's a valid url, so first of all use an url parser to get the info. Then you can decide what to do with it. I doubt a semantic parser is really what he wants, far more simple is to try the url out. If it doesn work, strip the last characters and try again...

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this link](https://www.codespeedy.com/check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url-or-not-in-python/), we can use the library **validators**.

For example:

```
import validators

valid = validators.url('https://codespeedy.com/')
if valid == True:
    print("URL is valid")
else:
    print("Invalid URL")
```

Comment: This lib can't  handle null-value

Answer (score 2):

I use this to search for all HTTP and HTTPS URLs. It works like a charm.

```python
URL_PATTERN = "http[s]*\S+"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll admit that I'm a little bit worried about an application that requires a regex like that to match URLs. That said, this seems to work for me:

```
((https?):((//)|(\\\\))+([\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+-=\\\.&](#!)?)*)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the most complete pattern I use:

```py
URL_PATTERN = r'[A-Za-z0-9]+://[A-Za-z0-9%-_]+(/[A-Za-z0-9%-_])*(#|\\?)[A-Za-z0-9%-_&=]*'
```

Comment: that's more common for any protocol such as ftp:// socks:// socks5h:// ..