# how to use a regular expression to achieve the following output?

Tags: python, regex

I am cleaning my data from urls I tried:

```
s = 'hello http://www.google.com I am william http://www.google.com'

from urlparse import urlparse

s.split()

clean = ' '.join([el for el in [i for i in s.split()] if not urlparse(el).scheme])

print(clean)
```

desired output:

```
hello I am william
```

However this time I would like to achieve the same output using
instead a regular expression.

Comment: This is an awkward issue. See https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex for some attempts at perfect url regexes. If you know your urls will always have a certain format, this problem will be greatly simplified.

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718633/python-regular-expression-again-match-url) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883049/regex-to-find-urls-in-string-in-python) and also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520031/whats-the-cleanest-way-to-extract-urls-from-a-string-using-python)

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is a decent online, python flavored, regex tester .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use replacement

```
import re

s = 'hello http://www.google.com I am william http://www.google.com'
print(re.sub('http\S+\s?', '', s))
```

Prints

```
hello I am william
```