# Regex pattern for extracting website urls

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have data like:

```
https://github.com/abcd
http://www.abcd.com
gmail.com
B.E
1.Project
2.Project
Project 
1.2
5.Project
abcd.com
abcd.wordpress.com
linkedin.com/in/abcd
```

And I'm using the regex pattern as:

```
(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?[\w/\-?=%.]+\.[\w/\-?=%.]+
```

And my output is:

```
https://github.com/abcd
http://www.abcd.com
gmail.com  
B.E    
1.Project    
2.Project    
1.2   
5.Project   
abcd.com   
abcd.wordpress.com  
linkedin.com/in/abcd
```

Required Output:

```
https://github.com/abcd  
http://www.abcd.com   
abcd.com    
abcd.wordpress.com    
linkedin.com/in/abcd
```

Can someone tell me what changes I need to do in my regex to get the required output?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6718683/7965340

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python regular expression again - match url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718633/python-regular-expression-again-match-url)

Comment: well, according to this specific example you could just check for `".com" in s`. Are there more extensions possible?