# Parse URL with a regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to get the query name and values to be displayed from a URL.
For example, `url='http://host:port_num/file/path/file1.html?query1=value1&query2=value2'`

From this, parse the query names and its values and to print it.

Comment: The canonical question is *[How can I split a URL string up into separate parts in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449775/)* (2009).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that it's best not to use a regular expression and better to use `urlparse`, but here is my regular expression.

Classes like `urlparse` were developed specifically to handle all URLs efficiently and are much more reliable than a regular expression is, so make use of them if you can.

```
>>> x = 'http://www.example.com:8080/abcd/dir/file1.html?query1=value1&query2=value2'
>>> query_pattern='(query\d+)=(\w+)'
>>> # query_pattern='(\w+)=(\w+)'    a more general pattern
>>> re.findall(query_pattern, x)
[('query1', 'value1'), ('query2', 'value2')]
```

Comment: It might be worth elaborating on why regex is the wrong hammer for this nail.

Comment: Alright I think I explained it very briefly. Feel free to explain it better if you want :D

Comment: thank you jamylak. can you plase tel me how can v split it generically. for eg. if the query contains "name=asd&name1=qwerty", for this the above pattern ll not work. so instead of using name wat v can use in the query pattern. Since i'm new to python regex i'm asking this :)

Comment: See the commented out code, `query_pattern='(\w+)=(\w*)'`. That should work for any query.

Comment: oh sorry i haven't seen it sorry

Comment: Actually it should be `query_pattern='(\w+)=(\w+)'`, i don't think it will matter from previous pattern but anyway. :D

Comment: parsing urls with regular expressions is a terrible idea; when there's an urlparse module *in the stdlib* this is unforgivable.

Comment: That won't work for any query; hyphen-minus is a valid character in query string, as are exclamation mark, comma... see http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt

Answer (score 8):

Don't use a regex! Use [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html).

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(url).query)
{'query2': ['value2'], 'query1': ['value1']}
```

Comment: And in one line `urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse("http://www.example.com:8080/abcd/dir/file1.html?query1=value1&query2=value2").query)`

Comment: or `[pair.split("=") for pair in urlparse(url).query.split("&")]`

Comment: That may have to be updated for Python 3.