# Split URL with regex

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm trying to get two inputs from a URL into a view by using regular expressions.

My *urls.py* line looks like this:

```
(r'^blog/(?P<match>.+)/', 'blog.views.blog'),
```

And this is my view:

```
def blog(request, match):
    pieces = match.split('/')
```

However, if my URL is "root.com/blog/user/3" `pieces` only returns `[user]`.

In order for `pieces to return` [user],[3]`, a trailing slash has to be added to my URL: "root.com/blog/user/3/".

And as far as I know and according to my Python shell, the first URL should have returned `[user],[3]`.

Am I missing something? Or does Django actually split strings differently from Python?

Comment: do you want `user`, and `3` as 2 separate variables in the views?

Comment: It seems to be not a very good idead, actually, to get arguments this way. Are you sure you _really_ want to do this?

Comment: @karthikr yes, i have user = pieces[0], and number = pieces[1], however, with the first url, i get an error because the pieces list is out of range.

Comment: @kirelagin If there is another method that results in pretty URLs than I'm all ears.

Comment: @bcoop713 I think it is an issue with regex. Just answered the question. See if that serves your purpose

Comment: You should be having a separate view for users. The pattern will be `r'^blog/user/(?P<uid>\d+)$'`. Then you'll have another view for, say, posts with a pattern `r'^blog/post/(?P<postid>\d+)$'` and so on.

Comment: @kirelagin looks like the OP wants flexibility to send in key value pairs via url

Comment: @karthikr looks like the OP hasn't given enough thought to his URL scheme and doesn't have much experience with Django, so I'm trying to help with that.

Comment: The canonical question is *[How can I split a URL string up into separate parts in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449775/)* (2009).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your regexp doesn't match the whole URL because the pattern ends with a slash, and your URL doesn't.

But since regexp without an explicit `$` at the end matches *a prefix* of a string, if you'll have a look at your `match` variable you'll notice that it is `user/`, not `user/3` as you might expect.

*Update*: (more verbose explanation)

`r'^blog/.*/'` matches `[blog/user/]` and `[blog/user/]3` (square brackets used to denote actually matched parts).

If you try `r'^blog/.*/$'` you'll notice that `blog/user/3` won't match at all since there is not slash at the end.

Comment: Just so everyone knows, I forgot the dollar sign, the solution is (r'^blog/(?P<match>.+)/$', 'blog.views.blog'), and the above is the explanation of why it didn't work :)