# Split a URL into its components in Python

Tags: python, regex, urlparse

I have a huge list of URLs that are all like this:

```
http://www.example.com/site/section1/VAR1/VAR2
```

Where VAR1 and VAR2 are the dynamic elements of the URL. I want to extract only the VAR1 from this URL string. I've tried to use [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html), but the output look like this:

```
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.example.com', path='/site/section1/VAR1/VAR2', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

Comment: The canonical question is *[How can I split a URL string up into separate parts in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449775/)* (2009).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Alternatively, you can apply the `split()` method:

```
>>> url = "http://www.example.com/site/section1/VAR1/VAR2"
>>> url.split("/")[-2:]
['VAR1', 'VAR2']
```

Comment: rsplit is more efficient than split because it saves splits using maxsplit argument.

Answer (score 15):

You can remember this in general. Different sections of the URL can be obtained using `urlparse`. Here you can obtain the `path` by `urlparse(url).path` and then obtain the desired variable by `split()` function

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> url = 'http://www.example.com/site/section1/VAR1/VAR2'
>>> urlparse(url)
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.example.com', path='/site/section1/VAR1/VAR2', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urlparse(url).path
'/site/section1/VAR1/VAR2'
>>> urlparse(url).path.split('/')[-2]
'VAR1'
```

Comment: for python 3 it's `from urllib.parse import urlparse`

Answer (score 4):

Check this one. It is quite efficient, because it starts from the end of the string. With the *maxsplit* option, we can stop the number of splits.

Finally, you can use indexing to get the last two parts of the URL:

```
>>> url.rsplit('/',2)[1:]
['VAR1', 'VAR2']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply try

```
url = 'http://www.example.com/site/section1/VAR1/VAR2'
var1 = url.split('/')[-2]
```