# How to regex url with two groups?

Tags: python, regex

I got this url: `s3://dev-datalake-cluster-bucket-q37evqefmksl/raw/wfm/users.11315`

I need to have the following values:

1. dev-datalake-cluster-bucket-q37evqefmksl
2. /raw/wfm/users.11315

I tried so far this code below, but it keeps throwing me errors -

```
pattern = re.compile('s3://(?)/(?)', response_content)
print ( re.match(pattern, response_content) )
```

Comment: "?" is one character in regexp.

Comment: See [How can I split a url string up into separate parts in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/449811/3832970).

Comment: `(?)` looks like you have vaguely guessed how regexes might work and now that your guess has failed you've given up and are asking for help. Read a tutorial or some documentation on regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negated character class to grab this value using:

```
^s3://([^/]+)/(.*)
```

Your value is returned by captured group #1

**Code:**

```
>>> s = 's3://dev-datalake-cluster-bucket-q37evqefmksl/raw/wfm/users.11315'

>>> print re.findall(r'^s3://([^/]+)/(.*)', s)
[('dev-datalake-cluster-bucket-q37evqefmksl', 'raw/wfm/users.11315')]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SU40ka/3)

**Regex Breakup:**

- `^` - Line start
- `s3://` - Match literal `s3://`
- `([^/]+)` - Match 1 or more of any character that is not `/`
- `/` - Match literal `/`
- `(.*)` - Match rest

Comment: What about the second part?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`re.groupdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.groupdict)

```
>>> re_match = re.match(r's3://(?P<bucket>[^/]+)/(?P<item_path>.*)', s)
>>> re_match.groupdict()
{'bucket': 'dev-datalake-cluster-bucket-q37evqefmksl', 'item_path': 'raw/wfm/users.11315'}
```

[Pythex](https://pythex.org/) is a handy resource for regex.