# Regular expression for removing all URLs in a string in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to delete all the URLs in the sentence.

Here is my code:

```py
import ijson
f = open("/content/drive/My Drive/PTT 爬蟲/content/MakeUp/PTT_MakeUp_content_0_1000.json")
objects = ijson.items(f, 'item')

for obj in list(objects):
    article = obj['content']
    ret = re.findall("http[s*]:[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-/#~]+ ", article) # Question here
    for r in ret:
        article = article.replace(r, "")
    print(article)
```

But a URL with "http" is still left in the sentence.

```
article_example = "眼影盤長這樣 http://i.imgur.com/uxvRo3h.jpg 說真的 很不好拍"
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: The regex should be `"https?:[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-/#~]+ "` if you want to match both http and https prefixes.

Comment: A canonical question is *[How can I split a URL string up into separate parts in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449775/)* (2009).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple fix would be to just replace the pattern `https?://\S+` with an empty string:

```
article_example = "眼影盤長這樣 http://i.imgur.com/uxvRo3h.jpg 說真的 很不好拍"
output = re.sub(r'https?://\S+', '', article_example)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
眼影盤長這樣  說真的 很不好拍
```

My pattern assumes that whatever non whitespace characters which follow `http://` or `https://` are part of the URL.

Answer (score 2):

The URL starts with *http* and in your pattern you match `[s*]` which will match either a `s` or `*` in the [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

I think you are looking for

```
https?:[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-/#~]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lXiXwX/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/tm04ek)

```
import re
regex = r"https?:[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-/#~]+ "
article = "眼影盤長這樣 http://i.imgur.com/uxvRo3h.jpg 說真的 很不好拍"
result = re.sub(regex, "", article)
print(result)
```

Result

```
眼影盤長這樣 說真的 很不好拍
```

A shortened expression, which is a bit broader match, could also be matching a non whitespace `\S+` char one or more times, followed by a space zero or more times to match the trailing space as in your original pattern.

```
\bhttps?:\S+ *
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/szFYZC/1)

Answer (score 1):

Change the `[s*]` to `s?`. The former is a set of two characters. The latter is an optional character. There are websites like [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) that let you experiment with regular expressions in the Python dialect. It will explain the interpretation of each part of the regex.