# Split URL in Python

Tags: python, url, discord.py, last.fm

So, I have this URL: https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit/Significant+Other

I want to split it, to only keep the `Limp+Bizkit` and `Significant+Other` part of the URL. These are variables, and can be different each time. These are needed to create a new URL (which I know how to do).

I want the `Limp+Bizkit` and `Significant+Other` to be two different variables. How do I do this?

Comment: The canonical question is *[How can I split a URL string up into separate parts in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449775/)* (2009).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `https://www.last.fm/music/` in the URL to just get `Limp+Bizkit/Significant+Other`. Then you can split it in half at the `/` character to break it into two strings. Then the URL will be a list and you can access the indices with `url[0]` and `url[1]`:

```
>>> url = "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit/Significant+Other"
>>> url = url.replace("https://www.last.fm/music/",'').split('/')
>>> first_value = url[0]
>>> second_value = url[1]
>>> first_value
'Limp+Bizkit'
>>> second_value
'Significant+Other'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `str.split` method and use the forward slash as the separator.

```py
>>> url = "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit/Significant+Other"
>>> *_, a, b = url.split("/")
>>> a
'Limp+Bizkit'
>>> b
'Significant+Other'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to achieve this.

```
import regex as re

url = "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit/Significant+Other"
match = re.match("^.*\/\/.*\/.*\/(.*)\/(.*)", url)

print(match.group(1))
print(match.group(2))
```